# using appendTo to add many DIVs to HTML. Getting "unexpected token <" error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to display a div for each result in my database, and the HTML structure is set up in such a way that in order for each unique record to display correctly, I need to append a lot of HTML code to a DIV by using appendTo in the AJAX response.  Two questions:

1)  Does it make sense to have all this HTML code in my AJAX response?  It seems like there must be a better way to do this, and I just don't know what it is.  Can anyone point me in a better direction?

2)  I'm also getting an "unexpected token <" error on my second line of HTML code (noted below).

```
function getGoals() {
var account = <?php echo $account; ?>;
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {action: "get_goals", account:account}
});
request.done(function(response){
    $('.goals').remove(); 
    if(response.goals.length != 0) {

        for(var i = 0; i < response.goals.length; i++) {
            $('<div class="col-sm-6" class="goals">
                <div class="block">  //  <--this is the line of problem code according to dev tools.
                    <div class="block-title">
                        <h2>' + response.goals[i].goal_name + '</h2>
                        <h2 class="pull-right">Created: ' + response.goals[i].date_created + '</h2>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row gutter30">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h4 class="subHeader">Goal Amount</h4>
                            <h3 class="positiveNum">&#36;' + response.goals[i].goal_amount + '</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h4 class="subHeader">This is a header</h4>
                            <h3 class="positiveNum">&#36;' + response.goals[i].monthly_amount + '</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h4 class="subHeader">Target Date</h4>
                            <h3 class="positiveNum">' + response.goals[i].goal_date + '</h3>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gutter30">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="progress progress-striped">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" 
role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="' + response.goals[i].percent + '"" aria-valuemin="0"
 aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 'response.goals[i].percent + '%;">' + 
response.goals[i].percent + '&#37;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>').hide().appendTo("#goal-contain").fadeIn(900);
        }
    }
});
request.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus){
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});

};
```

Comment: main problem is have to escape line breaks in strings in javascript, or close quotes on each line and concatenate next line with `+`. When in doubt paste code into an online linter like jshint.com

Comment: You should seriously look into a templating library.  That is way too much HTML to put in your JavaScript.

Comment: Either add plus(+) at the end of each line or use a backslash. For more details view my answer below.

Comment: @Dennis - So I take it there is a performance hit from using this much HTML in my JS?  or just ugly?  I was considering using a templating library, but I haven't done enough research yet..

Comment: No real performance issue over a template because all the same work needs to be done anyway.  It's ugly and, more importantly, tough to maintain.

Comment: I think I will look into a templating engine.  After using @Learning's solution below and getting my code to work, I've already realized a couple of changes I want to make, and it would be great to be able to make them outside of JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript language performs automatic semicolon insertion at the end lines, so creating multiline strings usually ends up looking something like this:

```
var multiStr = "This is the first line" + 
    "This is the second line" + 
    "This is more...";
```

String upon string of concatenated JavaScript mess...ugly, slow, and ...ugly.  Many novice JavaScript developers don't know that there's a better way to create multiline strings:

```
var multiStr = "This is the first line \
    This is the second line \
    This is more...";
```

Adding a backslash at the end of each line tells the JavaScript engine that the string will continue to the next line, thus avoiding the automatic semicolon insertion annoyance.